# How to make python look for numpy at custom locations through cmake (for building a C++ shared object library)

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cmake

Context: We have included NumPy as a part of our C++ project to ship a shared object library. The code runs perfectly when we pip install NumPy at `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` (i.e the shared object file / Python Interpreter is able to find NumPy at this location ). However, if we install NumPy at some other location and pass it through `include_directories` in our CMakelists.txt its unable to find NumPy. It doesn't work even when I add the custom installation folder for NumPy to PYTHONPATH or PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables.

Additional context:
The code runs well if we build the script as an executable instead of a shared object library.

Issue:

```
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
import_array()
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘numpy